# Show failure message in onpage failure page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, messages

I'm trying to show some custom `failure messages` on onepage failure page in **magento 1**. How can I do this? I did the same for magento 2 using:

```
$this->messageManager->addError(__($msg));
```

And redirecting to corresponding page.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1:

**Notice:**

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addNotice("Notice message");
```

**Error:**

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addError("Error message");
```

**Success:**

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addSuccess("Success message");
```

Comment: Let me check it.